# Compile Error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I tried to compile simple code with **Visual Studio Code** and **GCC**, but it failed and following error message appeared.

```
//////////// LinkedList.h ////////////
#pragma once

typedef struct LINKEDLIST {
    Node* head;
    Node* cur;
    Node* before;
    int numOfData;
    int(*comp)(LData d1, LData d2);
}LinkedList;

typedef LinkedList List;
void ListInit(List* plist);


//////////// LinkedList.c ////////////
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"

void ListInit(List* plist) {
    plist->head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    plist->head->next = NULL;
    plist->comp = NULL;
    plist->numOfData = 0;
}


//////////// main.c /////////////
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"

List list;
ListInit(&list);
```

If I compile this code, an error **undefined reference to 'ListInit'** is occured.
So I compiled `LinkedList.c` separately and another error log is appeared like this:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I built it with `Windows Application`, not `Console Application`. But I couldn't find the option about it in **VS Code**.

How can I compile source code with console mode?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't defined the main function i.e. the starting point for the program
In case you are making a console Application the starting point is

```
int main()
```

In case you are making a Win32 Application the starting point is

```
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
```

While working with VS code the settings need to be manually changed
you should refer to
[VS code Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

and by default a console application is made
You should tweak your .json files accordingly

Comment: Ah, sorry. I put `int main(void)` correctly but I didn't write here. Anyway the problem is same. Also there aren't any "Empty project template" in VS code.

Comment: Which operating system are you using

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: What type of Launch.json you made did you choose windows or GDB

Comment: I selected GDB.